# How update price for variable product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a problem with update price for variable product

```
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_regular_price', (float)$meta_value  );

update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price', (float)$meta_value  );
```

I use it for product ID and product_variation ID

I check DB. This Field updated.

On shop and the product page shows the old price.
[image]

But on cart and checkout i see updated price
[image]

```
if ($_POST['departments']) {

    //convert string to array
    $vowels = array("[", "]", "\"", "\\");
    $departments            = explode(",", str_replace($vowels, "", $_POST['departments']));

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'departments', $_POST['departments']  );

    foreach ($departments as $key => $value) {

        $assign_product_id      = explode(",", str_replace($vowels, "", $_POST['add_product_to_campaign'][$key]));
        $assign_product_price   = explode(",", str_replace($vowels, "", $_POST['add_product_price_to_campaign'][$key]));

        foreach ($assign_product_id as $key_prod => $value_prod) {
            $meta_value = trim($assign_product_price[$key_prod], '\\');
            $product_id = trim($value_prod, '\\');
            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', $meta_value  );
            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', $meta_value  );

            $product_id            = (int)$product_id;

            global $wpdb;
            $variable_post = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE  post_parent = ' . $product_id);

            if ($variable_post) {

                foreach ($variable_post as $post) {
                    update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_regular_price', (float)$meta_value  );
                    update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price', (float)$meta_value  );
                }
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'departments' );
}
```

Comment: Can you please let me know which code you have used for header cart??? Can you please update the code in question so I can check it and will help you to fix this.

Comment: @TanmayPatel updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it.

I clear transients for variable product before update price:

`wc_delete_product_transients($post_id);`

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted.